# Payment form on my webpage

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing

I know I can't create my own payment gateway except if I don't have anything to do for two years from now :p.

But still I've seen a lot of websites that have a payment form on their website, like godaddy.com or panic.com (when buying Coda) and I didn't really found any website that offer this service, Paypal and 2CheckOut generally send the user to their website.

I've read some articles where they said that I can use the paypal API to have my own payment form and "communicate" with paypal.

I've been developing systems in php since a long time now but I'm really new to the world of online payment: I don't want a complete answer or walkthought just some tips or where to start.

Adv thanks

PS: I did a quick search on SO and didn't find exactly what I needed but If I'm mistaken and there's already a similar question I would delete this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at [PayProGlobal](http://www.payproglobal.com/). They handle all the e-commerce side, and integrate into your business. Although the "forms" are hosted on their site, you provide the templates so the forms can have your site's "look and feel".

Hosting payment forms directly on your web site is very problematic, since you'll have to deal with credit card data storage and transmission, VISA requirements compliance etc. Outsourcing all this, including fraud management and such, is a better idea.

PayProGlobal is one of the few "independent" providers left, most others were bought by DigitalRiver and run into the ground, I would stay away from DigitalRiver as long as possible.